# How can I get strings between two strings, where the two strings are repetitive?

Tags: c#

Given a string of n lines like:

> start-student--subject--end-student--start-student-marks-end-student-
>   -start-student-total-end-student-names of students-student-details-percentage-end-student-details--start-student-subject-end-student--start-student-marks-end-student-
>   -start-student-total-end-student-class-start-student-percentage-end-student-

My approach:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Data.txt");
int start = s.IndexOf("start-student") + 1;
int end = s.IndexOf("end-student", start);
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

i'm getting only one string:

"subject"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Using your code I'm getting "tart-student--subject--". Are you certain you are asking the right question, since the data you would be getting is quite random.

Comment: There isn't any loop here, so of course you are only going to get one result. Do you need help understanding loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Data.txt");
        var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "(?<=start-student)((?!end-student).)*");
        foreach(var m in matches)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces

> --subject--
>
> -marks-
>
> -total-
>
> -subject-
>
> -marks-
>
> -total-
>
> -percentage-

Comment: Above Code is working and i too found the below code is working well
Thanks For your help

Answer (score 0):

```
        string s = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\SampleXML.txt");
        Regex r = new Regex(@"start-student-(.+?)-end-student");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
        string[] c = new string[mc.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
        {
            c[i] = mc[i].Groups[0].Value;
        }
        string result = string.Join("\n", c);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```